# Issue Parsing image with Formidable Error NodeJS Express MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, formidable

I've got this problem, which I've never had this before and I've used this same function to upload an image and save it into MongoDB for ages. Here is the function I use:

```js
router.post("/profile-pic/:id", async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        let user = await User.findById(req.params.id);
        if (!user) return res.status(404).send("User not found...");
        let form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
        form.keepExtensions = true;
        form.parse(req, async (err, fields, files) => {
            if (err) return res.status(400).send("Image could not be uploaded.");
            else if (files.profilePic) {
                if (files.profilePic.size > 1000000) {
                    return res.status(400).send("Image can not be larger than 1MB");
                }
                await User.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: user.id }, {
                    profilePic: {
                        data: fs.readFileSync(files.profilePic.path),
                        contentType: files.profilePic.type
                    }
                }, { useFindAndModify: false });
                res.send("Image uploaded successfully.");
            }
        });
    } catch (ex) {
        console.error(ex);
        next();
    }
});
```

And here is the error I started getting:

```js
(node:10084) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to Buffer failed for value "{
  data: <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 02 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 ff ed 00 9c 50 68 6f 74 6f 73 68 6f 70 20 33 2e 30 00 38 42 49 4d 04 04
00 00 00 00 00 80 ... 68443 more bytes>,
  contentType: 'image/jpeg'
}" at path "profilePic"
    at model.Query.exec (C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\InstaCringe\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4351:21)
    at model.Query.Query.then (C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\InstaCringe\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4443:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(node:10084) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:10084) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will
terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

*EDIT* User Schema:

```js
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, trim: true, required: true, maxLength: 60 },
    email: { type: String, unique: true, trim: true, maxLength: 100 },
    password: String,
    isAdmin: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    profilePic: { type: Buffer, contentType: String },
    photos: Array
});
```

Can anyone help me crack this case ... I have no clue why I'm unable to upload images anymore.
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Hi there, can you please add the schema for the `User` model to the question. Just in case it's very large and you can't share the whole thing, I want to see the type you've set for `User.profilePic`

Comment: Done. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Looks like this is not the right data "buffer" should receive.
It should receive the array itself not what your trying to put:
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#buffers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why you are having the error:**

There is a mismatch between what you have in your schema and what you are trying to save in the database. Specifically, `profilePic` in your schema is defined as:

```
profilePic: { type: Buffer, contentType: String }
```

Note that mongoose would ignore the `contentType` property as it's not a valid option for type `Buffer`.
*Why is mongoose considering `contentType` an option?* you may ask; it's because when Mongoose finds a nested property named `type` in your schema, Mongoose assumes that it needs to define a SchemaType with the given type, and every other property in the object are considered [SchemaType options](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#schematype-options) for that type. You can read more about the `type` key [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#type-key).

In your `post /profile-pic/:id` endpoint, you're trying to save this:

```
profilePic: {
  data: fs.readFileSync(files.profilePic.path),
  contentType: files.profilePic.type
}
```

Mongoose would try to cast the object you are trying to save to what was specified in the schema(Buffer), however, it's not able to do that and that is why you are getting the `CastError`.

**The Fix:**

1. If it's an option, removing the  `contentType` property in the schema and saving the Buffer value directly would be the easy fix. The schema becomes something like this:

```
profilePic: { type: Buffer }
```

And saving becomes something like this:

```
profilePic: fs.readFileSync(files.profilePic.path),
```

now, `profilePic` would hold the buffer value of the image.

2. However, I guess the reason you had a `contentType` property in the first place was to deliberately store the `contentType` of the buffer value, if you are still interested in that piece of data, you would have to update your schema to create a space for it, something like this:

```
profilePic: { 
  data: { type: Buffer },
  contentType: String 
}
```

Notice that unlike before, contentType is not declared as an option for type Buffer, rather, it's a nested property with its own type.

Now, you can go ahead to save the `profilePic` data just like you were doing before:

```
profilePic: {
  data: fs.readFileSync(files.profilePic.path),
  contentType: files.profilePic.type
}
```